# How do i detect a number in a message in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm still learning about discord.js, and i want to know how do i detect a number when an user sends a message

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + " modify" + " name")) {
    (db[message.author.id].InGameName) = message.content.slice(17);
```

after the message the user will be freely to put his name, but i don't want the user can use numbers on it, and cancel it, only want to know how to check if after the slice, there's a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Regex` to find the number ranging from `0` to `9` in a string like this -

```js
message.content.match(/[1-4]/g) // will return an array
```

So you can check for the length of the array to see if there is a number.

For example

```js
"sp1 20".match(/[1-4]/g) //will output ["1","2","0"]
```

Comment: If you just want to know whether or not a number exists in the message, you could just do `if (message.content.match(/[0-9]/g))` instead of checking the length of the outputted array, given that the match will return false if it doesn't find anything. As for regex, [this](https://regex101.com/) is one of many good websites that you can use to experiment with and learn more about the different things you can do with regex.